# ASP C# Add Row to Table and Survive Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looking for a simple way to create a running table of data input by a user in a submit form.  The table really just needs to add a row with data that was just input, but more importantly, survive postback.

The table should have a header, then a row per 'set' of data entered the last submit.

For example:

```
<asp:Table ID="lastRecordTable" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled"
    AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:TableHeaderRow>
        <asp:TableCell>A</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>B</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>C</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>D</asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>1</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>2</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>3</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>4</asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Code Behind:

```
TableRow row = new TableRow();
TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
cell1.Text = 1.ToString();
cell1.Text = 2.ToString();
cell1.Text = 3.ToString();
cell1.Text = 4.ToString();
row.Cells.Add(cell1);
row.Cells.Add(cell2);
row.Cells.Add(cell3);
row.Cells.Add(cell4);
lastRecordTable.Rows.Add(row);
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You need to add the new row to your datasource, so when the table receives data after postback it refreshes.   If you don't have a datasource, you'll have to shove this in a session variable.

Comment: No datasource outside of keeping a running tally written to the table on the webpage.  I'm assuming this can be done this way.  I'll take a look at a session variable and see if I can incorporate/use it.  For the above example, the code would be this? Session["1"] = 1.Text; with a callback on Page_Load?  Would the table populate multiple rows this way?

Comment: You'd need to store an array of rows that equated to the entire row list in the table.  Websites like basic HTML and WebForms "forget" anything between postbacks unless specifically stored in a session variable or a data source.  They are unable to store data on their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I got to work:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {                

        }    

        lastRecordTable();

    }
```

Table Method:

```
    public void lastRecordTable()
    {
        if (Session["lastRecord"] == null)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("1");
            dt.Columns.Add("2");
            dt.Columns.Add("3");
            dt.Columns.Add("4");

            Session["lastRecord"] = dt;

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();           
        }
        else
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["lastRecord"];
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Modify Table:

```
    protected void buttonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            //do stuff here
            DataTable dt = Session["lastRecord"] as DataTable;
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["1"] = "A";
            row["2"] = "B";
            row["3"] = "C";
            row["4"] = "D";
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
            Session["lastRecord"] = dt;
            lastRecordTable();
    }
```

ASP:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" 
         AutoPostBack="true"></asp:GridView>
```

I'm very new to asp c#, so not 100% sure this is 'correct', but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Because you add the rows dynamically, you need to (re)create them on every page load, and that includes a PostBack. So move the adding of the row outside the `IsPostBack` check.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //not here
    }

    //but here
    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
    TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
    TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
    TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
    cell1.Text = 1.ToString();
    cell1.Text = 2.ToString();
    cell1.Text = 3.ToString();
    cell1.Text = 4.ToString();
    row.Cells.Add(cell1);
    row.Cells.Add(cell2);
    row.Cells.Add(cell3);
    row.Cells.Add(cell4);
    lastRecordTable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

You don't need `ViewStateMode="Enabled"` and `AutoPostBack="true"` for this to work.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work.  The table gets written, updated with 1 row with incorrect data, but only 1 row ever gets added thru repeated 'submissions'.  I may try another approach.

Comment: Because you are adding rows dynamically, you need to recreate them. And if it is more than 1 you need to store that rowcount in a Session or ViewState.

Comment: Is it possible to add the row in code upon submit, then store the entire table in a ViewState, then retrieve the table via ViewState in postback?

Comment: It seems that as I'm learning, a table can't be stored in ViewState, but a DataTable can.

Comment: Yup, store the datatable in the viewstate, add you can keep ading rows.